# Setting up a URL Redirect in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I need to have a single, non-reg-ex pattern url to either rewrite or redirect to.  I d'loaded URL Rewrite 2.0 for IIS7 but each option requests for a pattern to test, of which I have none.

I created an Inbound Rule but I don't know what to do about the Pattern field.  I'm not searching for anything more than an exact url to point to.  This is what I entered:

Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Exact Match
Pattern: http://foo.bar/virtual/url/ (ignore case checked)
Action Type: Redirect
Redirect URL: http://foo.bar/?blah=1&meh=3&etc....
Redirect Type: 302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found an excellent tutorial on how to do this.  Turns out it's a mapping entry, no regex required.  Thank god!

[URL Rewrite Walkthrough](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/506/url-rewrite-module---video-walkthrough/)